# Sql- enforcing referential integrity on sub tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have three tables:

**`property`**

```
`id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`alias_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`primary_category` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`second_category` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`reference_number` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL,
`no_of_bedrooms` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`no_of_bathrooms` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

**`property Rental`**

```
`property_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`minimum_rental_months` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`minimum_rental_years` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`maximum_rental_months` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`maximum_rental_years` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`available_from` DATE NOT NULL,
`available_to` DATE NOT NULL,
`type_of_letting` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`price` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`deposit` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`additionals_included_with_rent` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
```

**`property Sales`**

```
`property_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`price` DECIMAL(10,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

The situation is that a property can either be a rental property or a sales property. It needs to be one of the other. property_id is a foreign to property in both sales and rental. However with this structure a user could in effect create a property that does not belong to rental or sales. I need to put some constraint in so a property must in either of the sales or rental tables.

I would then need to query to find all properties and the associated details.

Can someone please let me know the best way of me ensuring a property must either belong to rental or sales in this instance.

Comment: Yes that is correct a property could belong to either sales or rental. However i need to put a constraint in place that states that property must belong to either of these tables. I other words it must be a sales or rental property. It cannot exist without belonging to either rental or sales. At the moment it can be created stand alone.

Comment: i think this is called Polymorphic Associations

Comment: a suggestion was to add rental and sales to the property table and CHECK (property_rental_id IS NOT NULL OR property_sales_id IS NOT NULL)- does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: MySQL has not implemented `CHECK` constraints.

Comment: See my answer here: [MySQL Cross Table Constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820151/mysql-cross-table-constraint/11820500#11820500). Replace `'B'` and `'C'` with `'R'` and `'S'`.

Comment: thanks I have implemented this- in your example quick question- in table b and c is it best to add a foreign key to other tables or put contraints on with triggers

Comment: I prefer FKs. Th eonly thing that is not taken care in that answer is how to enforce that a `property` is either Sales or Rental, and not none of them. This cannot be done with FKs alone (not in MySQL). You'll need to write procedures (transaction) for Inserting into the tables (making sure that when a row is inserted at property table, a row is inserted too, in one of the others.)

Comment: type is rental or sales- a foreign key exists in property table that references type to enforce this. Am i looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15243/discussion-between-ypercube-and-matthew-chambers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe would result in a [chicken-or-the-egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) problem. You cannot insert into the appropriate “subtable” first, as the foreign key `property_id` requires the general entry to exist first. But neither can you insert into the general table first, at least if you could express the constraint you're asking for here. And as you cannot insert into two tables simultaneously, that would mean you cannot insert your data at all, unless you disable consistency checks for a while, which I'd consider really bad style.

I can see no clean solution to this at the databse constraints level. So I suggest you deal with possible inconsistencies (i.e. properties of unknown type) at the application level.